# DALI - How switches and sensors communicate in DALI Bus

Tags: dali

How the switches and sensors are communicating in the DALI Bus consists of an application controller and control gears?
What are the contents of the packet sent from these devices?

I was going through Google and I didn't get any clear image of how they communicate and control the light.

Comment: How they communicate is covered by IEC62386-103 and the -300 series. Configuring a system such as assigning switches to control groups of gear is only partly standardised - the facilities and messages are all specified but how it is done can vary by supplier and situation to allow for flexibility,

Answer (score 1):

They communicate with the DALI protocol, a command packet is sent to bus about button being pushed to e.g. recall a preset about state of lights in a room and the luminaries receive this command to select a preset and then they set their light level based on what was stored to this preset.

The DALI bus is a shared bus where any device can initiate a transmission and other devices can respond to it. It's basically an optoisolated open collector bus that any device can pull low while the DALI power supply keeps it high.

DALI packet is just a manchester encoded burst containing a couple of bytes, with preamble and some addressing and command bits.

You can read more about [DALI basics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface) on the Wikipedia page about it.

Comment: Then how the address works in this case, how can we assign a particular switch for controlling a particular control gear?

Comment: I don't know the details as the process is manufacturer specific with custom DALI system design programs, but you need to tell the switch what kind of messages to send from each button, and then you need to tell the lights what they do when they receive some kind of messages.